# Best way to add Class instance to a collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am not sure about the right way to tackle this problem, and therefore I would like your opinion on the matter. I'm would like to have a collection of instances like the following:

```
Person P = new Person();
P.Name = 'John';
P.Surname = 'Dough';

var People = [];
People.push(P);
```

Is this possible to code the above in Javascript (or Jquery, Angular..)? Any Blog I can follow or read further?

Comment: if you define function `Person` your code work

Comment: I use domain prototypes as wrappers for my data in angularjs all the time without any problems. Give it a try and see how far you get.

Comment: can you explain what try do?

Comment: I don't really understand what the question is.

Comment: Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour] for more information about what makes a good question. Generally speaking, Stack Overflow is not good for opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about defining `Person` "class":

```
var Person = function() {
};

var P = new Person();
P.Name = 'John';
P.Surname = 'Dough';

var People = [];
People.push(P);
```

or without `function` - just with simple object:

```
var P = {
  Name: 'John',
  Surname: 'Dough'
};

var People = [];
People.push(P);
```

Comment: i think you should add previous version also, with literal object :-)

Comment: @Grundy Ok, added previous too.